# Vertical content slider for wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

Does anyone know a vertical category content slider plugin for wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it is widely used : 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slidedeck-lite-for-wordpress/

Comment: Only PRO version slide vertically, i'd like to find a free plugin